# AngularJS $watch variable and reevaluate ng-class expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

I'm trying to implement a bookmark-like function into my app and have to watch a variable, which stores all the bookmarked ID's. Based on that variable I have to tell `ng-class` to reevaluate it's function expression so the class `bookmarked` get's added or not.

How do I tell `ng-class` to run again when the variable `$scope.Bookmarks` changes?

```
<a ng-repeat="event in events"
   ng-class="isBookmarked(event.id)"
   class="icon__bookmark"></a>
```

Comment: how is this related to jquery?

Comment: Is the isBookmarked(event.id) not getting called when bookmarks are updated.

Comment: Share more information, controller code. angularJs automatically call  isBookmarked if any change happened  in scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the bookmark ID's are being changed in code handled by angular (such as in a controller, a directive, a service, an $http callback, etc.) then you don't need to do anything at all. Angular will automatically re-evaluate `isBookmarked(event.id)` when it needs to in order to ensure that the UI is always up to date.

If, for some reason, the updates *must* be done outside of code that is handled by angular (such as in an external library), then you can manually force angular to update. However, it is *highly recommended* to just ensure that the code is handled by angular. You can usually do this, but it depends on the situation.

If you need to force it, then use `$scope.$apply` as follows:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  // Write code here to update bookmark ID's
});
```

Comment: This worked for me! For some reason, my ngClass was not re-evaluating my scope.currentTime var. ng-class="{cliptexthighlight: amHighlighted(currentTime,clipText)}"  so I put in: $scope.$apply(function() {
                        $scope.currentTime=currentTime;
                    });  and that forced the ngclass to re-evaluate

Comment: Yes, if the `$scope.currentTime=currentTime;` is done within a piece of code that is not called by angular (for me, this often means that it is in a regular JS callback function such as an event handler), then the UI will not be updated with the new value on the scope. That's when you must use `$scope.apply`, as you've done :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the class you want to add a class named "bookmarked" to the anchor tag and that isBookmarked returns a boolean, use this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XXLR6/1/)):

```
<a ng-repeat="event in events" 
   ng-class="{bookmarked: isBookmarked(event.id)}" 
   class="icon__bookmark">{{event.name}}</a>
```

You should not have to call $apply if the bookmarks array is within the controller, please see the fiddle I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$route.reload()`. It works very well for directives that are only evaluated once when the page is loaded (like the type that uses JQuery to do DOM manipulation).